# Decoding request entities with unfiltered

Tags: scala, unfiltered

Using [Unfiltered](http://unfiltered.databinder.net/Unfiltered.html), respecting a request's `Accept-Encoding` header is made trivial by the `GZip` kit.

What I cannot seem to find, however, is how to *accept* a gzipped request entity. It's perfectly legal for a client to declare an HTTP header of `Content-Encoding: gzip`, and servers should honour it. This doesn't appear to be the default unfiltered behaviour, nor can I find a built-in solution.

Am I missing an obvious solution, or do I need to manually handle this case? If the later, I'd be interested in pointers in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's not supported natively, even though it's not terribly hard to implement: https://github.com/unfiltered/unfiltered/issues/201